# Comparar fechas de un array en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

En mi base de datos tengo fechas correspondientes a feriados las cuales a través de una consulta guardo en un array. Lo que quiero es controlar que si la primer fecha del array menos la fecha "desde" ingresada por el usuario tiene un resto igual a 0, me cuente 1 y siga la comparación con la siguiente fecha para luego guardarla en una variable y utilizarla más adelante en la ecuación de días.

Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa el período 21/12/2022 a 05/01/2023, debería contarme 1, ya que 25/12/2022 menos 21/12/2022 es 4 y su resto es cero, y del 01/01/2023 (segunda fecha del array) menos 21/12/2022 es 11, lo cual su resto no es cero.
En resumen, lo que quiero es que me guarde en una variable cuántos registros del array cumplen con esa condición.

El problema es que no logro que haga esa comparación, ya que solo me compara la primera fecha del array y no pasa a la siguiente.

Pego el código:

```php
if(isset($_POST['ingresar'])){
    $usuario=$_SESSION['usuario'];
    $num_func=$_POST['funcionario'];
    $nom=$_SESSION['nombre'];
    $ape=$_SESSION['apellido'];
    $jefe=$usuario.' - '.$nom.' '.$ape;
    $desde=$_POST['desde']; 
    $hasta=$_POST['hasta']; 
    $fecha1=new DateTime($_POST['desde']);
    $fecha2=new DateTime($_POST['hasta']);
    $control_fecha= $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
    $dia=intval('1');
    $control_fecha2=$control_fecha->days + $dia;
    $pendiente='Pendiente';
                    
    //Datos del funcionario
    $reg=$_POST['funcionario'];
    $reg_cuatro="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE numFunc='$reg'";
    $query_reg=$conexion->query($reg_cuatro);
    $array_reg=$query_reg->fetch_assoc();
    $regimen=$array_reg['regimen']; 
    $nom_func=$array_reg['nombre'];
    $ape_func=$array_reg['apellido'];
    $sec_func=$array_reg['seccion'];
    
    $feriados="SELECT feriados FROM feriados WHERE feriados>='$desde' && feriados<='$hasta' && tipo='No Laborable'";
    $datos = mysqli_query($conexion, $feriados);
    $arrayDatos = mysqli_fetch_array($datos);
    $fer=$arrayDatos['feriados'];
                    
    if($query_feriados>0){
        $contar=0;
        for ($i=0; $i <=count($arrayDatos); $i++) {
            $fecha_array=new DateTime($fer);
            $ver=$fecha_array->diff($fecha1);
            $ver2=$ver->days;
            if ($ver2%4==0) {
                $contar=$contar+1;
            }else{
                $contar=$contar+0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que `mysqli_query()` devuelve un recurso (no los datos en sí mismos), para obtener los datos tienes que recorrer ese recurso usando alguno de los métodos *fetch*.

Si tu consulta devuelve una sola fila, tú puedes aplicar una sola vez el método *fetch*, obteniendo así la primera fila. Por ejemplo aquí en tu código: `$arrayDatos = mysqli_fetch_array($datos);` vas a tener en `$arrayDatos` **únicamente la primera fila de resultados**. Si quieres las filas sub-siguientes tienes que seguir aplicando el método *fetch*. Es por eso por lo que los resultados que traen varias filas suelen leerse dentro de un bucle (`while` por lo general), como podrás ver en el [Ejemplo 1 del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Por otra parte, quizá el método más adecuado aquí no sea `mysqli_fetch_array()`, porque el mismo te traerá los datos dos veces (como array numérico y asociativo). Dado que quieres usar el estilo asociativo, puedes usar directamente [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Aplicando todo lo dicho anteriormente, tu código debería funcionar de este modo:

```
$feriados="SELECT feriados FROM feriados WHERE feriados>='$desde' && feriados<='$hasta' && tipo='No Laborable'";
$datos = mysqli_query($conexion, $feriados);
$contar=0;
/*
    En cada iteracción del bucle
    $row representará cada fila de resultados
    mientras haya filas, porque el bucle
    irá aplicando el método fetch
*/                
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos) ){
    /*
       Evitaremos crear variables innecesariamente
       en varios casos, aligerando así el código
    */
    $fecha_array=new DateTime($row['feriados']);
    $ver=$fecha_array->diff($fecha1);
    if ($ver->days%4==0) {
        /*
           Esto incrementa el contador en 1
           y el else no hace falta, pues no tiene sentido
           sumarle 0 a una variable ...
        */
        $contar++;
    }
}
```

#### Advertencia de seguridad

Tu forma de ejecutar la consulta es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Un usuario mal intencionado podría manipular los datos de entrada y provocar graves daños en tu servidor, acceder a información sensible, modificar o borrar información e incluso colocar archivos dañiños en el contexto del servidor (sí, desde instrucciones SQL, en algunos casos, se pueden crear/guardar archivos en el servidor). Considera blindar el código usando consultas preparadas.